# KalmanFilter Tracking in openCV - Program received signal SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

I wanted to test the KalmanFilter for tracking purposes and found several tutorials which all look pretty similar overall (as it is mostly initializing openCVs KalmanFilter and setting up parameters).

I went after this implementation: https://github.com/screename/Kalman-Filter-Tracker/blob/master/KalmanFilterTracker.ccp

I'm having trouble testing it now though because whenever I start the program it crashes. There's no build-errors but when I start the debugging it shows a short message of **"Program received signal SIGSEGV - segmentation fault.**

The Call Stack shows that there's problems with **mat.hpp** in the line 574:

```
int i = i0/cols, j = i0 - i*cols;
```

and also at line 1043:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline _Tp& Mat_<_Tp>::operator ()(int i0)
{
     return this->at<_Tp>(i0);
}
```

**Within the KalmanFilter class these lines seem to be troubling:**

```
measurement(0) = x;
measurement(1) = y;
```

with

```
Mat_<float> measurement;
```

and initializing it with

```
measurement(2, 1);
measurement.setTo(Scalar(0));
```

Any idea on what might be causing the problems here and/or how to fix it? I tried a few things before but haven't found the cause so far.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i bet you wanted:

```
Mat_<float> measurement(2, 1);  // alloc 2 rows, 1 col
measurement.setTo(Scalar(0));
```

not:

```
Mat_<float> measurement; // an *empty* Mat.
measurement(2, 1);       // invalid access on an *empty* Mat (would be out of bounds, too)
```

Comment: This might be the cause. I got it in a separate class and created measurement in the header file. Here I can't put Mat_<float> measurement(2,1) which is why I thought it would be possible to create the Mat and allocate the rows/cols when initializing the constructor of my class. In the posted example he did the same so I thought it would be possible. How can I do this best in a separate class/header?

Comment: I guess one can do it with measurement = Mat(4,1,CV_32F) then? ^^ at least it's not crashing anymore now. Yep, seems to work now. Thanks for your answer though, didn't think about that anymore.

Comment: yep, just wanted to say that. use a constructor.